# AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTkFont', i imported customtkinter?

Tags: python, fonts, customtkinter

Does someone know, why I get this error?
I imported customtkinter the correct way and already redownloaded it, do i have to import it seperately?
I import `customtkinter` and get this error:

AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTkFont'

when executing this piece of code:

`label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="WUA", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Verdana", size=45)) label1.pack(pady = 20, padx=20)`

Comment: I can't find any references to `CTkFont` in the `customtkinter` source code...are you sure it exists? [Here's the repo](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/tree/master/customtkinter) if you're curious

Comment: Hey JRiggles, there is. If you scroll fully down under utility you will see CTkFont.
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkFont

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the problem...it says at the top of the [utility wiki page](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkFont): "Widget will be available with version 5.0.0!" - the current version is 4.6.3

Comment: OOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHHHH, thanks so much I read it to fast i guess.

Comment: No worries! for now, I'd say stick with `from tkinter.font import Font` :)

Comment: Yes i'm now trying that but now i get TypeError: tkinter.Label() got multiple values for keyword argument 'font'?

Comment: How are you implementing it? It should be something like `tkinter.Label(parent, text='Hey', font=('Comic Sans MS', 12, 'bold'))` for example...to be honest, I don't even think you need to import `Font` here.

Comment: It still gives me the same error as before, multiple values. I just use
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter

Comment: What's the actual line of code you are using?

Comment: label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, font=('Comic Sans MS', 12, 'bold'), text="words")
label1.pack(pady = 20, padx=20)

Comment: I think you need to use the keyword `text_font` as opposed to `font` for a `CTkLabel` - [see here](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/CTkLabel)

Answer (score 0):

```py
font= customtkinter.CTkFont(weight="bold",size=45)
```

use this

and read this doc may it help you

[image]

Comment: Changing the parameters won't address the OP's problem. If CtkFont did not exist the error will persist regardless of the parameters used.

Comment: font= customtkinter.CTkFont(size=11, weight="bold", family="Algerian")

This one is working in my system 

customtkinter==5.1.2

This version I am using right now

Comment: self.control_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.gun_frame, text="Select weapon category", font= customtkinter.CTkFont(size=11, weight="bold", family="Algerian"))
        self.control_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=0)

Comment: Yes, the previous answer from JRiggles and the comments showed it was an incompatible version.  You are using 5.1.2 which is after 5.0.0 and has the class.  The OP, from last November, did not yet have this version.